# Numerical Analysis of Lambert Function

Tags: real-analysis, numerical-methods, dynamical-systems, lambert-w

For a mathematical project I want to analyse the following function:
$R_{\infty} = 1 + \frac{W(\epsilon  e^{-\epsilon})}{\epsilon}$, in which the $W$ stands for the Lambert function. I have no experience with this function and after some research on internet I'm still stuck. I need to analyse this equation, thus I need to find a relation between $R$ and $\epsilon$. How can I do this? I tried mathematica for a numerical analysis but I don't get it to work.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Is $\epsilon \to 0$ or  $\epsilon \to \infty$ ?

Comment: No, $\epsilon$ is arbitrarily chosen, so it can be any value we want it to be but it is a parameter, normal values are anywhere between $0$ and $3$. I should have added that, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For "small" values of $x$, you could use Padé approximants built at $x=0$ and get
$$R(x) = 1 + \frac{W(x \, e^{-x})}{x}\approx \frac{2+6x+\frac{8 }{3}x^2 }{1+4x+\frac{10 }{3}x^2}$$ which is quite good up to $x=2$ (for this value of $x$, the exact value of the function is $\approx 1.10886 $ while the approximation gives $\frac {74 } {67 }\approx 1.10448$).

Comment: How did you find this approximation? Did you use software or just algebra? And can I also use the Padé approximant built at $x=1$?

Comment: When I use mathematica, I fill in the following: 
FullSimplify[PadeApproximant[1 + ProductLog[x*e^(-x)]/x, {x, 0, 2}]], but this gives me a completely different solution

Comment: @Mathbeginner. First, I am a fanatic lover of Padé approximants. Second, what does Mathematica give you ? I am afraid by $\color{red} {e}$; replace it by $\color{red} {E}$ and come back.

Comment: I did this: FullSimplify[PadeApproximant[1 + ProductLog[x*E^-x]/x, {x, 0, 3}, and this gives me $\frac{60+6x(1+x)(55+28x)}{30+x(195+384x+218x^{2}}$

Comment: @Mathbeginner. I suppose that your syntax is nor correct. Try FullSimplify[PadeApproximant[1 + ProductLog[x*E^-x]/x, {x, 0, {2,2}}]]  and you will probably get my result. Please tell me if I am wrong or not.

Comment: now I do get the same answer, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I am using $x$ instead of $\epsilon$. With $R(x) = 1 + \frac{W(x  e^{-x})}{x},$ Maple gives the two asymptotic expressions:

$$R(x) \sim 2-2x+4x^2-\tfrac{28}{3}x^3+24x^4+O(x^5), \quad x\rightarrow 0$$

$$R(x) \sim 
1+e^{-x}-xe^{-2x}+\tfrac{3}{2}x^2e^{-3x}-\tfrac{8}{3}x^3e^{-4x}+O(x^4e^{-5x}), \quad x \rightarrow \infty$$

Here the used Maple commands

```
> f := x ->1 + LambertW(x*exp(-x))/x;
                                                              LambertW(x exp(-x))
                                                f := x -> 1 + -------------------
                                                                       x
> series(f(x),x=0);
                                                          2         3       4      5
                                             2 - 2 x + 4 x  - 28/3 x  + 24 x  + O(x )
> series(f(x), x=infinity);
                                                                2           3           4
                                          1         x      3/2 x           x           x
                                    1 + ------ - ------- + ------- - 8/3 ------- + O(-------)
                                        exp(x)         2         3             4           5
                                                 exp(x)    exp(x)        exp(x)      exp(x)
```

If you want to compute / approximate the $W$ function in the intermediate range, have a look at [Having Fun with Lambert W(x) Function](https://arxiv.org/abs/1003.1628) and https://github.com/DarkoVeberic/LambertW

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I was looking for. Do you mind sharing how you computed this with maple (sorry, not familiar with maple, just working with mathematica so far but I guess it's similar)

Comment: Actually, I should evaluate this for $\epsilon<1$ and $\epsilon>1$, does that mean I can use $x \righattow 0$ and $x \rightarrow \infty$ for those values as well?

Comment: For Maple commands see edit. You can use the expressions for $\epsilon \ll 1$ or $\epsilon \gg 1$ but not for intermediate values, there you would use the pure Lambert W function.